# How to click on the browse button of this inputfile using selenium in JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, select

I don't know how to click on the browse button of an inputfile using Selenium. ([InputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXlkY.png))

Indeed, the input part, and the browse button are part of the same WebElement, and I don't know how to split them, to be able to click on the browse button. ([InputFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS21K.png))

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to click directly on the input tag ? In a browser you do not need to click on "Browse", you can also click on the text zone to open the popup. The behavior should be the same in Selenium.

Comment: Verify if the element is within a iframe.

Answer (score 1):

It's an `input` tag of type `file`. You can directly use the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("PATH_OF_FILE_TO_UPLOAD);
```

Then simply click on `OK`

Comment: In fact, I can't use sendKeys, I can't write anything inside the input part. But I have realized that if I double click on the input part, it opens the browse file fialog.

Comment: By using sendKeys you are passing the file location inside the input tag.  So what I suggested is equivalent to click on the browse button and then select the expected file.

Comment: But I can't with selenium! I can't click on the browse button to select the image.

Comment: But, as I told you, i'll try to double click to open the browser file dialog. Thank you, you gave me this idea :)